# Dynamically Changing animation speeds on custom views

Tags: java, android, android-animation

First off, I'm not a prodigy when it comes to android. Just getting that out there.

I need an image to rotate constantly, and when I provide input, to update the rotation speed. Currently, I'm creating a new ObjectAnimator every time I click a button. This takes a value from a text field and applies it to the ObjectAnimator as its duration. This does work, but it resets the animation each time I click the button. I need the animation to smoothly change speeds each time I click.

I feel like ObjectAnimator might be the wrong thing to use here, but I don't know what better options I have.

One thing to note, I'm stuck at a max API of 18.

```
public class SpinActivity extends Activity {

  private CustomView customView;
  private Button button;
  private EditText input;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spin_activity);

        //Init Variables
        customView = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.spinner_custom_view);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spinner_button);
        input = (EditText) findViewByIdR.id.speed);

        //Set up the button to animate the custom view
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                    float fSpeed = Float.parseFloat(txtSpeed.getText().toString());

                    customView.animateBitmap(fSpeed);
              }
        });
  }
```

}//end SpinActivity

public class CustomView extends View {

```
  private static final String TAG = CustomView.class.getSimpleName();

  private Bitmap dialSpeedOuter;
  private Context context;
  private FrameLayout activityFrame;


  public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
  }


  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (dialSpeedOuter == null) {
              BitmapFactory.Options vmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
              vmOptions.inDensity = 800;
              vmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
              dialSpeedOuter = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.spinner, vmOptions);
        }
  }

  public void animateBitmap(long speed) {
        long spinDuration = speed; //sets duration in ms

        ObjectAnimator spin = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this , "rotation", 0.0f, 360.0f);
        spin.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
        spin.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        spin.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        spin.setDuration(spinDuration);

        spin.start();
  }
```

}//end CustomView

Comment: You can use animation drawable, and it allows you to provide the frame images + the time it takes to animate between frames

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't AnimationDrawable only used for frame animation? I only have the one image I need rotated.

Comment: It sounds like a single image being rotated, not a set of images, so that wouldn't apply... Have you tried not using any of the animation objects and manually handling the rotation via the View's onDraw method (ie. using canvas to rotate the drawable being displayed) and then having a separate Thread handle the "animation" (ie. increment the animation speed by reducing the sleep time between invalidation calls)

Answer (score 1):

Object animator is going to be easier to use than manually handling the view's rotation with canvas.

For simplicity, I wrote my own little demo inside of the default Android Application Project (the newest one that has the fragment) where the time goes down by 1/2 everything. You should be able to adapt to your code as necessary. (you also don't need to put it in the set. I just put it there cause I copied code from some of my other code and forgot to take it out before I tested).

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    Button btn_B;
    TextView hello;
    ObjectAnimator mAnimation;
    AnimatorSet transSet;
    Float valuefrom=0f;
    Float valueto=-360f;
    long speed= 500;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        btn_B= (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        hello= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        btn_B.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {         
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Float save = (Float) mAnimation.getAnimatedValue();
                Log.d("TAG", "Value" +save);
                valuefrom= save;
                valueto= save-360;
                speed= speed/2;
                transSet.cancel();
                doObjectAnimator();
            }
        });
        doObjectAnimator();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void doObjectAnimator(){
        mAnimation= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(hello, "rotation", valuefrom, valueto);
        mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        mAnimation.setDuration(speed);
        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        transSet= new AnimatorSet();
        transSet.play(mAnimation);
        transSet.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to my comment, something along the lines of this:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

  private static float ROATION_ANGLE_INCREMENT = 1;
  private static float ROATION_SPEED_INCREMENT = 10;

  private Thread animationThread; 
  private long sleepTime = 100;
  private float rotationAngle = 0; 

  public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(rotationAngle, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2));
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
  }

  public void startRotation(){
      isActive = true;
      animationThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
          public void run() {
              while(isActive){
                  try{
                      rotationAngle = (rotationAngle + ROATION_ANGLE_INCREMENT) % 360;
                      CustomView.this.postInvalidate();
                      Thread.sleep(sleepDelay);
                  }
                  catch(Exception e){ }
              }
          }
      });
      animationThread.start();
  }

  private void onIncreaseSpeed(){
      sleepTime -= ROTATION_SPEED_INCREMENT;
  }     

  private void stop(){
      try{
          isActive = false;
          animationThread.stop();
      }
      catch(Exception e){}
  }        
}
```

I did that without testing or a compiler, so you're definitely going to have to adjust it a bit as well as all the default values to match your desired results...

You may also want to make it extend the Layout, not the View, and have the View live inside it, so that the image doesn't get cut off.

Comment: There was a post of SO, a dude was complaining about the fact that this type of animation was doing strange things upon screen rotation. Multiple images were drawn over the canvas.

Comment: You should NEVER sleep threads in android. You should instead use handlers with post delayed actions. Also before executing the run method through (scheduling another handler) you must check if the activity is finishing or not, as that could cause a crash if it is - the method for that is "isFinishing()"

Comment: @LenaBru can you point me to where you read about "NEVER sleep threads in android," because that just sounds ridiculous. Yes, using a Handler's postDelayed function is an option, but that doesn't mean it's the only one, nor does it make it the best. In this situation, Thread.sleep() would work just fine. As for you reading about another post where multiple images were being drawn: that has nothing to do with the Canvas, and has everything to do with that person incorrectly using it.